# Make a triangle for the right side of a 'li'

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I have the following HTML defined:

```
<ul class="steps d-flex">
   <li class="step">Basic Details<div class="triangle triangle-right"></div></li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.steps li {
    @extend .text-center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1 1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: $grey-600;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to have a triangle pointing to the right of the div like so:

[image]

Notice how payment has a triangle that looks like it's pointing to 'done'

How do I do this?

Comment: read this: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-breadcrumb-navigation-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a breadcrumb / steps-progress component is quite simple using CSS `clip-path` and CSS `calc()`. Here I use a CSS var `--s` for the arrow "size" which you can set to any desired value:

```css
/*QuickReset™*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 1rem/1.4 sans-serif; }

/* STEPS COMPONENT */

.steps {
  --s: 2rem; /* arrow size */
  display: flex;
}

.steps > * {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  /* Arrow shape */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--s)) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%, 0 100%, calc(0% + var(--s)) 50%);
  margin-left: calc(var(--s) * -0.7);
}

.steps > :first-child {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--s)) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: 0;
}

.steps > :last-child {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, var(--s) 50%);
}

.steps .is-active { background: #0bf; }
```

```html
<nav class="steps">
  <a href="">Details</a>
  <a href="" class="is-active">Payment</a>
  <a href="">Done</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: What does the --s do?

Comment: I named that CSS variable `--s` like *"size"*. You can rename it as you like. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties It's used as the distance, length of the *arrow* tip. Change the value and you'll see what it does exactly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a `chevron` element. An easy way to do it using CSS. After that you can implement it to your example.

I suggest you to use `flexbox` technology, it's much easier and elegant way to complete these kind of tasks.

Here is an example of your question.

```css
.chevron-right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(5.5);
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100px
}

.chevron-right::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
  top: 4px;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.payment {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.done {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="payment">Payment</div>
  <i class="chevron-right"></i>
  <div class="done">Done</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Given your provided HTML and CSS, it looks like you're trying to create a triangle using a div with a class of triangle-right. To make this triangle point to the right, you can use the ::before or ::after pseudo-element, coupled with the border trick to form the triangle. Here's how you can do it:

```
.triangle-right::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  /* centers the triangle vertically */
    left: 100%;  /* places the triangle to the right of the containing 
div */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;  /* adjust size as needed */
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;  /* adjust size as needed */
    border-left: 10px solid $grey-600;  /* adjust size and color as 
needed */
    transform: translateY(-50%);  /* fine-tunes the vertical centering 
*/
}
```

With this CSS, the triangle will point to the right and will appear on the right side of the  with the class triangle-right. Adjust the border sizes as needed to change the size of the triangle.

Comment: If you make the code into a runnable snippet it would be helpful (I can't at the moment see how it creates a white chevron shape, does it?)

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)