# how can i change this design?

Tags: html, css

I am working on CSS in which I am making a progress bar.
My code is as follows:

```css
.breadcrumbstyle ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li a {
  width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #ACACAC;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  /* Adjusted margin to reduce space */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #ACACAC;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.breadcrumbstyle ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbstyle w-full items-center mt-2 text-[#FFFFFF] leading-trim-normal leading-3 text-cap font-open-sans font-normal text-xs ">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#1">Qualified</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#2">New </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#3">Working</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#4">Nurturing</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#5">Converted</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With this I am getting a progress bar like this progress_bar.

[image]

But with this code arrow shape of bars is not proper. The shape of arrow I want is `required_bar`. How can I change shape of my bars exactly as same that of required as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Here's an example that uses a simple CSS var to set the arrow size: [breadcrumb progress with arrow border](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77261197/383904)